# customize cursor

Tags: actionscript-2

so I have this code for customizing a cursor inside my game.

Mouse.hide()
startDrag(mc_cursor,true)

it works fine but the problem is it cannot click on buttons, and I really need to know why it doesn't work. please help me guys, anyone.

Comment: Could you post a complete extract of your code so that we could help?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the anchor point of your movieclip mc_cursor? When creating the movieclip, you can choose the anchor point. in case of a movieclip for cursor, you'll need to select the top left anchor point.

This should solve your problem. If it doesn't solve your problem, let me know that problems you are facing.

[In case you wanted to know why, the mouse cursor drags the movieclip for the anchor point. So if the anchor point is set at the center then the cursor drags it from the center.]

Comment: the anchor point is the top left one, my problem is it can click buttons on the first scene, but when it comes to the next frame it cannot click on any buttons anymore.